# Unmark a word using mark.js

Tags: javascript

I have some strings, I am passing to mark.js to highlight.

```
"item1 and item2"
"item2 and item3"
```

In a normal paragraph I would have:

**item1** is the first object **and** **item2** is another one.

Those items in bold are what mark.js highlights but I would like to exclude several words like [and, or].

How can I exclude them or unselect them?

Comment: Why don't you filter manually the strings you want to filter before passing them to `mark` function?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ignoreWords = [
    "the",
    "and"
  ],
  keywords = [
    "item1 and item2",
    "item2 and item3"
  ],
  optimizedKeywords = keywords.map(function(val) {
    for (var i = 0, len = ignoreWords.length; i < len; i++) {
      val = val.replace(new RegExp(ignoreWords[i], "gmi"), "");
    }
    return val;
  });
new Mark(".context").mark(optimizedKeywords);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/8.8.3/mark.min.js"></script>
<div class="context">
  item1 and item2<br> item2 the item3
</div>
```

As soon as [this PR](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/pull/114) is merged you can replace words with wildcards to also match sentences with disabled `separateWordSearch`.